# Language Reference, Font-family

Tags: fonts, font-face, webfonts, typography, font-family

There are three basic languages used on my website. I put `lang="en"` in html tag. In the CSS file I write the following:

```
body {

 ...
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 font-size: 10pt;
 ...
}
```

So, if the text on the website is in English either Russian it uses the web font called **Open Sans**. And this works OK.

Now I want to make so when I write a text in Armenian it to use a web font **Arian AMU**, but it doesn't work this way: `font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Ariam AMU';`

In the CSS, I write

```
:lang(hy) {
    font-family: 'Arian AMU';
    font-size: 10.5pt;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

And I put `lang="hy"` in `p` tags when the whole text is in Armenian.

The question is, how can I make it so that if the language is Russian or English, it writes in `Open Sans 10pt` and when it's Armenian, `Ariam AMU 10.5pt` and line-height of 18px.

Answer (score 0):

The [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) [`:lang`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alang) has more [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the element selector `body`. This may cause issues when the two rules conflict, like in your case. Try specifying all the conflicting rules with the same specificity:

```
:lang(en), :lang(ru) {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

:lang(hy) {
    font-family: 'Ariam AMU';
    font-size: 10.5pt;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NJR6R/).

You can learn more about CSS specificity by reading these articles:

- [CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)
- [Specifics on CSS Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)